# Errors and isFetching shared across components in React, Redux, and Redux Saga app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-saga

I have a React Native app using Redux and Redux Saga. I'm also using a pattern from the Ignite starter, and which I've also seen used in many other places, where the state has an "isFetching" flag and an "error" property to represent when API calls are being made and errors that occur as a result of the API calls.

I have read in several places that it's recommended to split your Redux store by domains or features. And I've also read that it's not generally a good idea to have a 1:1 relationship between your components and Redux files.

Now, let's say there are several screens in my app where I can make a payment or manage credit cards.  So in my case, I'm thinking "Payment" might be a good domain. For example, maybe I can make a payment using a credit card on screen A, and add a new credit card on screen B. I have two sagas to handle this: a getCards saga and makePayment saga. They both have corresponding "request" actions where the isFetching flag is set to true. From there, they each make several API calls, transform data, etc. and then update the PaymentRedux state with the new data. Once they are complete, they update the isFetching flag to false. If an error occurs, they update the state with an appropriate error type.

But should one screen's loading indicator or error state really be tied to a result that could have been initiated on another screen? For example, if my payment fails for some reason on screen A, then I navigate to screen B, do I want screen B to know about the potentially unrelated error that occurred on screen A?

So my questions are:

1. Would this be a sensible split for my Redux state in the first
   place? And should I be sharing state across my different screens like this?
2. How do I handle the errors/isFetching, if at all? Would I have multiple "isFetching" flags, one per operation? Would each screen just subscribe to the particular error types they are interested in?

Just wondering what the recommended patterns are. Advice would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe in your situation it would be better to split this reducer in two, so you would have a payment reducer and a creditCards reducer. The creditCards reducer would be responsible of all the data regarding adding, removing and modifying credit cards, while the payment reducer would take care of the payment state, such as if it was successful, what's the order number, the credit card used, etc.

This is very subjective, as there isn't a right way to do stuff in Redux. If you don't think having two reducers is really necessary, maybe you could split the payment reducer on itself, thus having both states on the same reducer as below:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  payment: {
    error: null,
    fetching: false,
    ...
  },
  creditCards: {
    error: null,
    fetching: false
  }
}
```

This way, you just need to implement the selectors and the action handlers according to the way you modelled your state.